# Adding sublayout to Item specific device programmatically

Tags: sitecore

For one of a project requirement I suppose to add a sublayout to item at runtime, and this sublayout should be added to devices ( Default , Printer ), So I used the following code:

```
                Item item = GetDatabase().GetItem(Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(itemId));
                if (item != null)
                {
                    LayoutField layoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
                    LayoutDefinition layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);

                    string[] targetedDevices = new string[] { "{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}", "{46D2F427-4CE5-4E1F-BA10-EF3636F43534}" };

                    foreach (var device in targetedDevices)
                    {
                        DeviceDefinition deviceDefinition = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(device);
                        RenderingDefinition renderingDefinition = new RenderingDefinition();
                        renderingDefinition.ItemID = sublayoutId;
                        renderingDefinition.Placeholder = "column-content";


                        deviceDefinition.AddRendering(renderingDefinition);
                    }
                    // Save the layout changes
                    item.Editing.BeginEdit();
                    layoutField.Value = layoutDefinition.ToXml(); ;
                    item.Editing.EndEdit();
                }
```

My Question is, Is there another way of selecting the presentation devices like sitecore API? As I am hardly coded the IDs of the targeted devices.

Comment: Why not just add the component to all devices in the presentation details of the standard values and then just hide the component for devices where it should not be shown using the Rules Engine/Personlisation?

Comment: Yes I can do that, but what I am looking for is if I can get the device I need using sitecore API like: Sitecore.Context.Device.ID.ToString() but this retrieve the current content device what If I need specific device other than context.

Comment: Where is the above code running? When the editor makes a change/creates an item or when rendering an item to the user? I don't think there is an API for these, since you are able to add your own device definitions it's easy for you to extend, or even delete a Sitecore provided device, and therefore does not make sense to provide "Devices.Default" (or similar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not seen any specific API a far as I have navigated though Sitecore.Kernel.dll unfortunately. Maybe there is some third party sitecore extension that warp and extend this functionality, but again, I am now aware about that.

**Important point to note:** I noticed from the code mentioned above: You are accessing

```
item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]
```

and that is valid for Sitecore version up to 7. But as Sitecore 8 introduced Versioned Layouts you should use

```
item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField]
```

instead. Hope that helps.